# Flutter Firestore Populate ListView with a single document Object list

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've been looking everywhere and cannot find any resources on this. Using Flutter I'm trying to get a Future Listview builder to populate using a single document in firestore using a map/object. My current structure in firestore looks like this

```
 (Collection)Restaurants
      (Document)California
           (Map)Locations
                (String) A0 = Los Angeles
                (String) A1 = LA Restaurant 1
                (String) A2 = LA Restaurant 2
                (String) A3 = LA Restaurant 3
                (String) B0 = San Diego
                (String) B1 = SD Restaurant 1
                (String) B2 = SD Restaurant 2
                (String) B3 = SD Restaurant 3
```

Every resource I find would put each of the Map objects in their own document then retrieve the collection as a whole to populate the list. Is it possible to use the Map from a single document to do the same? If so how would you retrieve it?

```
 body: new Container(
    child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getList(),
        builder: (_, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }else{
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data["California.Locations"].length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index){

                  if(snapshot.data["California.Location"] == "A0"){
                    return ListTile(
                      title: new Center(child: Text(snapshot.data[index].data,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),),),
                    );
                  }else if(snapshot.data["California.Location"] != "A0") {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["name"],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      onTap: (){
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> RestaurantDetail())
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
               });
         }}),
       ),
```

My if statements are to get LA and San Diego as headers in the list.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what is your request.. Can I ask you for further explaination?

Comment: Sure! All I'm trying to do is create a listview in flutter using only one document. This document would have a Map inside with all the information. The Map in the document is title Location and this would house all the information I would like to post within the listview.